# Preg_match: select a number range between 3 and 12 excluding 7, 9 and 11

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to match the following condition, to select a number range between `3` and `12` excluding `7`, `9` and `11` and must be preceded by the following operators `>` or `<`and then an optional `=`.

i.e `> < = 3,4,5,6,8,10,11,12` so the following matches are true: with or without spaces `> = 3`, `< = 12`, `> 2`, `< 13` false `< = 3`, `> = 12`, `> > 4`, `= =`, `= > 5`. I've tried the following code which matches all the numbers and characters above but I'm getting stuck when I want to limited to one occurrence of `>` `<` `=` etc so `>>` will return as a match, I've tried `/>{1}` but that doesn't work. I'm new to regular expressions, thank you in advance.

```
    $var = '>=12';
    if (preg_match("/>|<|=|[3-6]|8|10|12/", $var)) {
       echo "A match was found." . $var;
       return true;
    } else {
       echo "A match was not found." . $var;
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your true and false examples do not match the logic you described verbally.  Please clean up your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I beautified the question a bit (in a peer review), though not sure I understood it right as well, as it was missing the punctuation and logical delimiters as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the groups into parenthesis and only within the groups use the `|` separator:

```
"/(>|<)=?([3-6]|8|10|12)/"
```

Also potentially prefix with `^` and end with `$` to enforce full string matching.

Comment: There's something wrong with description or the code sample from author. It might be `>|<|=` at the very beginning, not just `>|<`

Comment: This works great thanks. I added a further condition to check for <3 , <=3 and >12 which I didn't want to match, as follows $pregmatch= array('<3', '<=3', '>12'); foreach ($pregmatch as $preg) {//second check 
   
    if (strpos($var, $preg) !== FALSE) { 
        echo "Error !Not valid imput. ".$preg;
    $var = null;   //reset
    }